# How to use .htaccess rewrite rule to simulate routing with no framework?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

All PHP framework I know use routing.

My goal is to use that routing technique without any framework:
ex:
Instead of having something like:

```
viewProfil.php?username=tom&id=10
```

I would like to get that

```
viewProfil/tom/10
```

(for any numbers of get parameters)

So I can hangle in viewProfil.php

```
$username = $_GET[0];
$id = $_GET[1];
```

Is such thing possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, in the php:

`$params = explode('/', $_GET['q']);`

Comment: will this work with ANY page ? and with any number of params ?

Comment: yes, you can use this with any pages(if I understand correctly)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^viewProfil/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ viewProfil.php?username=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

To get more examples, see this tutorial: [Advanced .htaccess examples](http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-advanced-htaccess-examples)

Comment: Question is to route **for any numbers of get parameters**

Comment: "Any numbers of get parameters " and any page